# Google Charts Timeline - Divider/separator/tab

Tags: charts, google-visualization, timeline

I want to make my gantt chart easier to read. Therefore I want to separate some columns from each other:

[image]

As you can see in the picture that I uploaded, I called the first 3 columns "Linha 1", etc... Using "[' Linha 1 ', ' ', 0,150000 ],"

Is there a better way to divide/separate this columns ?

To make my self clear I have uploaded a second picture, it was made in excel. In there it's possible to get a better understanding of the gantt chart.

[image]

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['timeline'] }).then(function () {
var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Máquina' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'NºEncomenda' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Inicio' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Fim' });
dataTable.addRows([
[' Linha 1 ', ' ', 0,150000 ],

['Repuxagem 1001 ', '0257 ', 11000,16000 ],
['Repuxagem 1001 ', '0087 ', 3000,5000 ],
['Repuxagem 1001 ', '0173 ', 7000,11000 ],
['Repuxagem 1001 ', '0189 ', 5000,7000 ],
['Repuxagem 1001 ', '0177 ', 0,3000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0087 ', 40000,42000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0015 ', 19000,26000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0226 ', 12000,14000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0227 ', 36000,38000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0189 ', 5000,7000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0177 ', 8000,11000 ],
['Recartilhado 1005 ', '0178 ', 31000,33000 ],
['Impressão Topo ', '0087 ', 3000,5000 ],
['Impressão Topo ', '0173 ', 7000,11000 ],
[' Linha 2 ', ' ', 0,150000 ],
['Repuxagem 2001 ', '0015 ', 0,7000 ],
['Repuxagem 2001 ', '0284 ', 7000,8000 ],
['Repuxagem 2001 ', '0178 ', 8000,10000 ],
['Repuxagem 2001 ', '0293 ', 10000,15000 ],
['Recartilhado 2005 ', '0257 ', 28000,33000 ],
['Recartilhado 2005 ', '0027 ', 26000,28000 ],
['Recartilhado 2005 ', '0284 ', 41000,42000 ],
['Recartilhado 2005 ', '0177 ', 33000,36000 ],
['Recartilhado 2005 ', '0293 ', 36000,41000 ],
[' Linha 3 ', ' ', 0,150000 ],

['Repuxagem 3001 ', '0027 ', 2000,4000 ],
['Repuxagem 3001 ', '4943 ', 8000,15000 ],
['Repuxagem 3001 ', '0226 ', 0,2000 ],
['Repuxagem 3001 ', '0227 ', 15000,17000 ],
['Repuxagem 3001 ', '0285 ', 4000,8000 ],
['Recartilhado 3005 ', '4943 ', 27000,34000 ],
['Recartilhado 3005 ', '0173 ', 38000,42000 ],
['Recartilhado 3005 ', '0285 ', 15000,19000 ],
['Recartilhado 3005 ', '0178 ', 45000,47000 ],
[' Outros ', ' ', 0,150000 ],
['Calf 1 ', '0087 ', 36000,40000 ],
['Calf 1 ', '4943 ', 15000,27000 ],
['Calf 1 ', '0177 ', 3000,8000 ],
['Calf 1 ', '0285 ', 8000,15000 ],
['Calf 1 ', '0293 ', 27000,36000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0257 ', 19000,28000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0015 ', 7000,19000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0027 ', 4000,7000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0284 ', 38000,40000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0173 ', 31000,38000 ],
['Calf 2 ', '0178 ', 28000,31000 ],
['Serigrafia Corpo ', '0027 ', 12000,26000 ],
['Serigrafia Corpo ', '0226 ', 2000,12000 ],
['Serigrafia Corpo ', '0227 ', 26000,36000 ],
['Máquina 265 ', '0177 ', 11000,31000 ],
['Máquina 265 ', '0178 ', 33000,45000 ],
 ]);
// re-label x-axis
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
var incrementBy;
var valueCurrent;
 var valueLast;
var labelIndex = 0;
var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
// find x-axis labels by fill attribute
if (label.getAttribute('fill') === '#000000') {
valueCurrent = parseInt(label.textContent);
if (labelIndex === 1) {
incrementBy = valueCurrent - valueLast;
}
if (labelIndex > 0) {
if (valueCurrent < valueLast) {
valueCurrent = valueLast + incrementBy;
label.textContent = valueCurrent;
}
}
valueLast = valueCurrent;
labelIndex++;
}
});
});
chart.draw(dataTable);
});
</script>
<div id="example3.1" style="height: 1200px; width:4000px"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: no options out of the box for this, but you can manually change the chart's svg on the chart's `'ready'` event...

Comment: Sorry sir, but I'm relatively new at coding. Any ideia/example how I could do that? Thanks!